# Azure Data Factory Until loop slow to end/terminate

Tags: performance, azure-data-factory, until-loop

We have an `until loop` in a `ADFv2` pipeline.

The time it takes to stop/terminate once the expression condition is met seems to corrolate between the length of time the `until loop` takes to completes its activities.

This particular `until loop` performs alot of activites and can take anywhere between 90-120 mins to complete.  So it takes almost as long to end/terminate (break out of the loop).

If I "hack" it so that it only performs a handful of activities it will quickly end and break once it's finished and the expression to terminate is met.

It's like a spinning wheel that keeps spinning even after the power is turned off. The momentum that was built up while connected takes a while to slow down and eventually stop.

Is this a known issue, how can I troubleshoot the exact cause here or fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect usage of *nested loop switch* could cause this.

Here is a *Until* component, and some activities after it:
[Until](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roAlP.png)

In the *Until*, some activities,
**Correct:**
[In until - correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDEvY.png)
**Incorrect (Slow to end/terminate):**
[In until - incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccf8A.png)

---

### Why?

For the incorrect case, the last activity *If waiting* depends on three activities, perhaps its behavior was counterintuitive.

```json
// pay attention to "dependsOn"
{
    "name": "If waiting",
    "type": "IfCondition",
    "dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "Set loop_waiting_refresh_status to True",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        },
        {
            "activity": "WeChatEP_Notifier Info Get new bearer",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        },
        {
            "activity": "Set loop_waiting_refresh_status to False",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```